# How do i show the sum of material prices of each product on a shopping cart in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a web app in rails 4 with basic shopping cart, which shows the name of the product, quantity and price, and in it lies my problem. The price comes from the cost of its materials, and since products can have many materials and materials can be used on many products, i made a table called product_cost.  I don't have a calculated price field because material prices can change at any time and consequently so would the product price, so i thought it wouldn't be productive.

Back to the cart, i need to show the price for each product on it, and for that, calculate the cost of all materials used on that product.

Heres a simple representation of the structure:

```
    Material Table
      Name
      Unit cost

    Product Cost Table
      Product ID
      Material ID
      Quantity of material

    Product Table
      Name
      Description
```

How do i approach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is a `many-to-many` relationship, So i expect your models (Material, ProductCost, Product) are implemented with [has_many_through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), I choose has_many_through way because you will be able to do something like

```
p = Product.find(1)
product_cost_records = p.product_cost # retrieve array of active-records of the bridge table between product and material
product_cost_records.map do |record|
  record.material.unit * record.quantity # (record.material) gets Material record associated to this bridge record
end.reduce(:+) # map will put the multiplication of (quantity * Unit) into an array then reduce will sum them up
```

I know it seems like a lot of queries will be performed, But this is the fastest solution i got, Please Notice that i didn't tried above code on a template application or something i'm just guessing relationships in your app, Hope this helps you.

Comment: Question, after the end.reduce(:+), how do i access the result?

Comment: Just answering my own question, I made a helper method on my controller, put the code you gave in it, and it returns the total to the method, which in turn returns it to where i need it in the view. Thank for the help man =D

Comment: Sorry for my late response and you are welcome :D @onildo